# Rename 2 files using shell script

Tags: shell, files, scripting, rename

I created a script called `rename_2_files.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
#_start
while getopts o: flag
do
   case "${flag}" in
       o) OPTION=${OPTARG};;
   esac
done
# declare variable
RENAME ="rename"
DEFAULT ="default"
# show all ExportP* files
ls '/home/dev/Documents/Work/info/Target_script/first'*
# rename file
if [["$OPTION" == "$RENAME"]]; 
then
   mv '/home/dev/Documents/Work/info/Target_script/first1.txt' '/home/dev/Documents/Work/info/Target_script/first1_ori.txt'
   mv '/home/dev/Documents/Work/info/Target_script/first2_SL.txt' '/home/dev/Documents/Work/info/Target_script/first2.txt'
fi
# show new name o files
ls '/home/dev/Documents/Work/info/Target_script/first'*

#_end
```

I run it using

```
sh rename_2_files.sh -o rename
```

Response:

```
rename_2_files.sh: 10: rename_2_files.sh: RENAME: not found
rename_2_files.sh: 11: rename_2_files.sh: DEFAULT: not found
/home/dev/Documents/Work/info/Target_script/first1.txt
/home/dev/Documents/Work/info/Target_script/first2_SL.txt 
rename_2_files.sh: 20: rename_2_files.sh: [[Rename: not found
/home/dev/Documents/Work/info/Target_script/first1.txt
/home/dev/Documents/Work/info/Target_script/first2_SL.txt
```

What are the problems in this side? Help me please...

Comment: Welcome, you should use [https://www.shellcheck.net/](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to check for syntax errors, also available as package in most linux distributions.

Comment: When setting a variable, the variable name has to be followed directly by the `=` sign, without any whitespace in between

Comment: Thank you to all. It was many syntax errors. The https://www.shellcheck.net/ is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I had many syntax errors in my script, but i am used  https://www.shellcheck.net/ to correct them.

Now my script ('rename_2_files.sh') is:

```
#!/bin/sh
#_start
while getopts o: flag
do
    case "${flag}" in
        o) OPTION=${OPTARG};;
        *)
    esac
done
# declare variable
RENAME="rename"
DEFAULT="default"
# show all ExportP* files
ls '/home/dev/Documents/Work/info/Target_script/first'*
# rename file
if [ "$OPTION" = "$RENAME" ]; then
    mv '/home/dev/Documents/Work/info/Target_script/first1.txt' '/home/dev/Documents/Work/info/Target_script/first1_ori.txt'
    mv '/home/dev/Documents/Work/info/Target_script/first2_SL.txt' '/home/dev/Documents/Work/info/Target_script/first2.txt'
elif [ "$OPTION" = "$DEFAULT" ]; then
    mv '/home/dev/Documents/Work/info/Target_script/first1_ori.txt' '/home/dev/Documents/Work/info/Target_script/first1.txt'
    mv '/home/dev/Documents/Work/info/Target_script/first2.txt' '/home/dev/Documents/Work/info/Target_script/first2_SL.txt'
fi
# show new name o files
ls '/home/dev/Documents/Work/info/Target_script/first'*

#_end
```

And, to call the execution of script i use:
`sh rename_2_files.sh -o rename`
or
`sh rename_2_files.sh -o default`

Wish you to all a nice day and a lot of success!